Windows 11 host computer randomly(?) loses network when waking from sleep if HyperV is running
I'll preface with the fact that I haven't yet figured out a consistent repro for this but:
My host computer is running Windows 11 Pro and has a wired ethernet connection. I have Hyper-V installed and have another Windows 11 Pro VM set up inside of it. What I have found is that under some condition if my host computer goes to sleep - once it is woken up I will no longer have an internet connection. Unplugging and replugging the network cable does nothing it seems only restarting resolves the issue (possible an ipconfig /release + /renew could solve it? will try the next time I hit this).
I thought the issue might be if I let the host PC go to sleep while I have an active connection into the VM open but I just tried that and no repro so it seems intermittent somehow.
This has only ever happened after setting up the Hyper-V + VM and only ever happens if the VM is actively booted and running.
Any thoughts on what logs I should pull here to be more helpful?
